# Cuts and discontinuities of multivalued complex functions with several variables

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation, several-complex-variables, branch-cuts

Can somebody recommend some literature regarding cuts and discontinuities of multivalued complex functions with several variables?

Thanks!